# Random "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." on Windows Azure Web app

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a Web API in ASP.NET to contact my MySQL database hosted on external server. I keep this Web API at Windows Azure and everything works fine but every ~30 minutes I get

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

It last for about ~30 minutes and then Web API works fine. I don't understand it. Can someone explain?

[image: Error message]

[image: Web API working]

Comment: i am having the same issue how did you fix it?

Comment: I moved my Web API to somee.com. I didn't fix it at Windows Azure.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me.. did you manage to fix it?